# SQL show only double entries with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables, table one has double entries in the erp_key column.

```
Table1
erp_key article_key
1       a1
2       a2  
3       a3  
3       a4  
4       a5  
5       a6  
5       a7  
6       a8
```

I found a way to detect those with the following query:

```
SELECT erp_key, Count (erp_key)
from Table1
group by erp_key
having Count (erp_key) > 1
```

Now I want to join the table below by using the article_key and have the 'descr.' and 'date' also included in the query output.

```
Table2
descr.  article_key date
a       a1          3-1-2017
s       a2          4-4-2017    
d       a3          5-4-2017    
f       a4          6-4-2017    
g       a5          7-4-2017    
h       a6          8-4-2017    
j       a7          9-4-2017    
k       a8          1-4-2017
```

I came to this query, hower `COUNT(erp_key)` is not correct I think. It does not count multiple erp_key entries.

```
Select erp_key, Table1.article_key, descr, date_, COUNT(erp_key) AS counter
From            Table1
full outer join Table2
on Table2.article_key = Table1.article_key
group by erp_key, Table1.article_key, descr, date_,
having COUNT(erp_key) > 1
ORDER BY erp_key ASC
```

Even after trying more than a day I could not find a way to do this with a SQL query. 
Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post the `join` query also?

Comment: add the tag of DBMS you are using

Comment: `article_key` points to the `erp_key`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return all articles with date and descr where ERP_Key is greater than 1:

```
select a.erp_key,a.article_key,b.descr,b.date
from Table1 a
    join  (SELECT erp_key
           from Table1
           group by erp_key
           having Count (erp_key) > 1) sub on sub.erp_key=a.erp_key
    join Table2 b on a.article_key=b.article_key
```

It might be clearer with the following query but less efficient:

```
select a.erp_key,a.article_key,b.descr,b.date
from Table1 a
    join Table2 b on a.article_key=b.article_key
where a.erp_key in (SELECT erp_key
                    from Table1
                    group by erp_key
                    having Count (erp_key) > 1)
```

Comment: The first query gives "SQL fault 8155: No column name was specified for column 2 of 'sub'." as result. the second one works. Thanks!

Comment: it was unnecessary. I just used your code. I'll deleted the extra column.

Comment: For future reference, nearly every time you find yourself using an IN(), it is more efficient to handle it with a join.

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
SELECT a.erp_key, Count (a.erp_key), b.descr. , b.date
from Table1 a, Table2 b
where a.article_key = b.article_key
group by a.erp_key
having Count (a.erp_key) > 1
```

Comment: Will that even run? You've not included the b.descr. and b.date in the group by.